# How to restrict ldap logins to specific users in opensuse

Tags: ldap, opensuse

I setup a little server and have it authenticating with ldap.. is there a way to restrict which ldap user can login via ssh without adding an account to the opensuse box?

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Create a group on LDAP using YaST's User and Group Management, for instance "serveradmins".
This will create a entry on your LDAP server under the group OU.

2 - Add the allowed users to this group, also using YaST

3 - On the servers you want to restrict the access, edit the /etc/ldap.conf, making sure the following instructions are present (uncommented), mind changing the DC= parts to your configuration:

> pam_groupdn cn=serveradmins,ou=group,dc=example,dc=com
>
> pam_member_attribute member

Let me know if this worked well for you. I have this working on OpenSUSE and Ubuntu machines.